# How to expect that a string contains exactly N of a particular character in Chai?

Tags: javascript, chai

I have string:

```
const hash = 'dwqdiojqwoidj@2323joij@oindoi2d@dndi2on@diodno@1';
```

How can I check if this string contains exactly five `@` characters?

I can check if string contains one `@`:

```
expect(hash).to.include('@');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count occurrences and then verify the count instead:

```
const hash = 'dwqdiojqwoidj@2323joij@oindoi2d@dndi2on@diodno@1';
const count = (hash.match(/@/g) || []).length;
expect(count).to.equal(5);
```

Comment: Good approach but I feel like `expect(hash.match(/@/g) ?? []).to.have.length(5);` matches the intent a bit more accurately.

Comment: i used `count` variable to make it more descriptive of what you're testing, i.e. "test that the count of '@' in a string is 5". Your approach works just as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
let isValid = 0
for (let i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
    if (hash.includes("@", i)){
       isValid++;
       if(isValid === 5) {
           // do something   (true)
       }
    } else { 
       // do something   (false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.to.match()`:

```
const hash = 'dwqdiojqwoidj@2323joij@oindoi2d@dndi2on@diodno@1';
expect(hash).to.match(/^(?:[^@]*@[^@]*){5}$/g);
```

or:

```
expect(hash).to.match(/^(?:[^@]*@){5}[^@]*$/g);
```

or:

```
expect(hash.replace(/[^@]/g, "")).to.eq("@@@@@");
```

or:

```
expect(hash.match(/@/g) ?? []).to.have.length(5);
```

or:

```
expect(hash.replace(/[^@]/g, "")).to.have.length(5);
```